# DynamoDB alternatives in terms of pricing? (Only pay what you use)

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, cloud, serverless, amazon-timestream

What are other cloud-based, serverless, managed databases that have a pricing system similar to DynamoDB? I'm specifically talking about the **On-Demand** mode of DynamoDB

By similar I mean, being able to pay per requests and per GB/Month or similar, instead of paying a fixed monthly fee, I understand this will mostly gear towards NoSQL databases but for me **it doesn't matter the type of database**.

Apart from DynamoDB, I have also found FaunaDB, but it lacks documentation and tools/integrations

It's important to note that I'm not considering pay per hour here, as that is irrelevant once you go to production.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar" pricing? The fact that it allows you to pay very little when your needs are still very small? What about the prices when your needs grow larger? What about their "pricing" is what you are looking for?

Comment: @NadavHar'El Well I thought the title was obvious, I want to be able to pay per request and per GB/month or similar, the fact that it is SQL or NoSQL doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

All of these have a monthly storage cost, and so I will only mention the read/write costs for each product.

[Amazon Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) is a SQL database that is priced based on the amount of "Aurora capacity units" you use for reads and writes with *per-second* billing. The database “pauses” itself while not in use, and you don’t pay for ACUs while the DB is paused. There is a minimum billed amount of 5 minutes every time it starts up.

[Amazon Timestream](https://aws.amazon.com/timestream/pricing/) (currently only in preview) is a NoSQL database that is specifically optimized for storing time-series data. Pricing is based on the size of the data that is written or read during a request.

Strictly speaking, [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) is *not* a database—it's an object store—but it has a per-request pricing model. You can use [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/) (per-second billing, one minute minimum) or [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/pricing/) (per request billing, based on the amount of data scanned) to query/analyze data that is stored in S3.

<s>[Azure CosmosDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/) is a NoSQL database and has a per-request pricing model.</s> it turns out that you have to pay for hourly provisioning of the request units.

[GCP Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/#pricing) is an Analytics Data Warehouse. It has two pricing models, including a "pay for only what you use" pricing model that based on the amount of data read or written.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Aurora Serverless you still pay per-hour, but you can configure it to shutdown upon x minutes of inactivity and scale automatically. And Azure CosmosDB is per-hour, you pay the provisioned throughput.

Comment: @Mojimi, you’re right about CosmosDB. I missed that when I was reading about the pricing.

Comment: @Mojimi, the documentation for Aurora Serverless is very clear that it is billed per-second, but I did neglect to mention that there is a minimum billed amount of 5 minutes every time the DB starts up.